# How can I monitor a FIFO for read and writes?

Tags: c++, c, linux, fifo

How should one monitor data that went through a FIFO ? Simply open and keep watching doesn't work, since if the monitor reads all bytes, the actual program that needs data will fail to receive the data.

Comment: You could play *man in the middle*, read from one pipe, write to another.

Comment: or you could write a wraper for the fifo class that monitors everything it recieves

Comment: You'll have to modify the kernel.  Tell us the end you're trying to achieve, there's likely a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what kind of FIFO you have there (pipe? socket? maybe you should elaborate more on your question in general), but the only case where I know about forward-reading is with sockets.

You can use `recv()` with the flag `MSG_PEEK` with the following effect:

> This flag causes the receive operation to return data from the
>                 beginning of the receive queue without removing that data from the
>                 queue.  Thus, a subsequent receive call will return the same data.

You can implement IPC with sockets, too ([unix(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/unix.7.html)), so you might want to add them to your project (if you are using linux/unix). If you want to know how to use sockets then you should read the man page: [socket(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/socket.2.html) and [socket(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/socket.7.html) or in case of Windows, [`recv()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`socket()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You might also want to try to use 2 FIFO's, one to your monitor and the other one from your monitor to your actual program. Then you simply read all incoming data with your monitor and filter the relevant parts and write them directly to your actual program. This might come in handy if you have multiple receivers inside your actual programs and want to split up the incoming data.

If you simply want to know whether there is data to read, you can use [select(2) or pselect(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) or maybe [poll(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html), or [`select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of the following system calls:

select()- source: man -s 2 select

pselect()- source: man -s 2 pselect

> select() and  pselect()  allow  a  program  to  monitor  multiple 
>   file
>          descriptors,  waiting  until one or more of the file descriptors become
>          "ready" for some class of I/O operation (e.g., input possible).  A file
>          descriptor  is considered ready if it is possible to perform the corre-
>          sponding I/O operation (e.g., read(2)) without blocking.

Note they are all I/O blocking calls.

ppoll()- man -s 2 ppoll

poll()- man -s 2 poll

Also read the difference between the both set of system calls: http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.14.shtml

And using pselect or ppoll is always better than select and poll for safer uses.